# Using tables in as arrays in vba, (index,match,vlookup functions)

Tags: arrays, vba, match, vlookup

Trying to create function in vba to perform a index match function. I am referencing a excel table, and I want to reference the headers, not column number. 
Below is the worksheet that I have created and works.

```
=VLOOKUP(C4, Table2, MATCH(C5,Table2[#Headers],0), 0)
```

When I put this function into VBA, I am having trouble making the array work. I think...

```
MATCH(C5,Table2[#Headers],0)
```

needs to start with codes like this below.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns ("d") 
ActiveSheet.ListObject("Table2[d]")
```

Comment: So? What is the question?

Comment: The `ListObject` has a [`HeaderRowRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.headerrowrange) property, which would correspond to `Table2[#Headers]`, but you can just refer to a `ListColumn` by its header. There's no need for `MATCH`.

Comment: `array1=ActiveSheet.ListObject("Table2[d]")`          `x=application.worksheetfunction.vlookup(3,Table2,array1,).value`       this doesnt work when I attempt it

Comment: The syntax is `ListObject("Tablename").ListColumns("Column Name")`. Now that I'm rereading this question, you probably want the [`Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.index) property of the `ListColumn`.

Comment: `Dim array1 As Variant
Dim x As Double

array1 = ActiveSheet.ListObject("Table2").ListColumns("d").Index
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(3, Table2, array1, 0).Value

 MsgBox (x)` what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a `ListColumn` by its header, and then use its [`Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.index) property.

If your lookup value is in `C4` and the column name is in `C5`, then try something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    With Sheet1
        Dim myTbl As ListObject
        Set myTbl = .ListObjects("Table2")

        Dim indx As Integer
        indx = myTbl.ListColumns(.Range("C5").Value).Index

        Dim result As Variant
        result = Application.VLookup(.Range("C4").Value, myTbl.Range, indx, 0)

        MsgBox result
    End With

End Sub
```

**Sample table and data:**

[image]